# image uploaded from java code to AWS Encyrpted S3 gets corrupted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading a image to AWS Encrypted S3 Bucket from my java code.Upload works.Image file gets uploaded but if i download the same file and open in my local it says **It looks like we dont support this format** error

I have also enabled binary support in my API Gateway

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and *be included in your question*.

Comment: Than.. share your code too